# Dealing with loading large amounts of data in keras

Tags: python, memory, keras, gpu

I have this keras code that uses some of the pre-trained models available in keras to predict the classes of some image data.

For example you call the function like this:

```
pre_features(Xception, lf_path, uf_path, batch_size, models_path, (299, 299), xception.preprocess_input)
```

Which means it will use the Xception keras model to predict the features of the files in lf_path and uf_path using data augmentation of the images to (299, 299, 3)

The code of the function is this:

```
def pre_features(MODEL, lf_path, uf_path, batch_size, models_path, image_size=(224,224), lambda_func=None):
    width = image_size[0]
    height = image_size[1]
    input_tensor = Input((height, width, 3))
    x = input_tensor
    if lambda_func:
        x = Lambda(lambda_func)(x)
    base_model = MODEL(input_tensor=x, weights='imagenet', include_top=False)
    model = Model(base_model.input, GlobalAveragePooling2D()(base_model.output))

    gen = ImageDataGenerator()
    train_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(join(lf_path,'train_set'), image_size, shuffle=False, 
                                              batch_size=batch_size)
    valid_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(join(lf_path,'valid_set'), image_size, shuffle=False, 
                                              batch_size=batch_size)
    unlabeled_generator = gen.flow_from_directory(uf_path, image_size, shuffle=False, 
                                             batch_size=batch_size, class_mode=None)

    train = model.predict_generator(train_generator, train_generator.samples)
    valid = model.predict_generator(valid_generator, valid_generator.samples)
    unlabeled = model.predict_generator(unlabeled_generator, unlabeled_generator.samples)
    with h5py.File(join(models_path,typ+"_gap_%s.h5"%MODEL.__name__)) as h:
        h.create_dataset("train", data=train)
        h.create_dataset("valid", data=valid)
        h.create_dataset("unlabeled", data=unlabeled)
        h.create_dataset("label", data=train_generator.classes)
        h.create_dataset("val_label", data=valid_generator.classes)
```

Now I'm using an ImageDataGenerator to load the data from disk in batches and then I predict the classes.

The problem I'm having is that I'm running out of memory on the GPUs of a Grid where I'm running this code and I get a bunch of errors like this

```
2017-09-06 01:05:01.216563: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gp
u:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
2017-09-06 01:05:03.984894: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1045] Creating TensorFlow device (/gp
u:0) -> (device: 0, name: TITAN X (Pascal), pci bus id: 0000:03:00.0)
2017-09-06 02:36:05.106652: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 4294967296 bytes o
n host: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
2017-09-06 02:36:05.135916: W ./tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/pool_allocator.h:195] could not allocate pinned h
ost memory of size: 4294967296
2017-09-06 02:36:06.234000: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:955] failed to alloc 3865470464 bytes o
n host: CUDA_ERROR_INVALID_VALUE
```

and in the end I get

```
Job killed after exceeding memory limits
```

I suspect that the problem is when I try to predict the outputs from the unlabeled generator since the unlabeled data is way bigger than the other generators (around 31000 images).

What would be the best way to predict this memory issues? any suggestions?

Comment: What current value of batch size are you using? Have you tried just reducing it?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro using 32 at the moment. I thought it was small enough but I can try reducing it

Comment: Yes, reduce it, even batch size of one should produce the same results but run successfully.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Ok will try! Thanks

Comment: What is your RAM size? I've been using about 80GB for training images 320x480 in a reduced U-net model. I sadly found out that it's impossible to work with my home laptop with 8GB.